# Create composite component around p:dataTable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, facelets, composite-component

In my application, I am using datatable in many facelets. And most of the datatable looks like below:

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{tableBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"  
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" selectionMode="single" selection="#{tableBean.selectedCar}" id="carTable" lazy="true"> 
......
</p:dataTable>
```

So it looks like I have this stuffs duplicated in all the facelets. I was thinking is there any way to create a composite components for this common stuff(p:dataTable properties) and use that in the facelets whenever I need

Please let me know if this is possible and if possible if you can guide me with some hints or tutorials on how to do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes,you can,http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=24167